# SonarQube TFVC Plugin with VSTS

Tags: sonarqube, tfvc, azure-devops

is it possible to make the TFVC Plugin of SonarQube work with VSTS?

If I want to use the Plugin to connect with the TFVC of our VSTS-Account I get a not authorized exception. I'm pretty sure that the credentials are correct. Or Are there any special rights which are needed for that?

```
19:54:37.632 ERROR - Unable to TFS annotate the project which raised the following authentication exception: TF30063: You are not authorized to access xxx.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection.
```

the configuration seems all correct, because the plugin works with a TFS2015-Server without any issues.

I'm Testing the plugin localy with the sonar Scanner V1.1.
SonarQube Version 5.2, TFVC Plugin Version 2.1

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this scenario is not supported yet. I ran into the same problem and I found the following issue on the backlog of the SonarQube team:

> With the current TFVC Annotate plugin code author information is not seen for VSO hosted builds, this MMF is to enable the same.

You can find this information on: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-85

So until they fixed it I fear you'll need to disable this plugin...